# I can't read from RS232 in arduino mega

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I've a load cell conected to http://us.ohaus.com/en/home/products/product-families/T3P-US.aspx which has an RS232 interface. The interface work perfectly connected with the PC (9600 8N1). I've configure it to write the weigth every second, and it's displayed in hyperterminal.

In the other hand, I've an arduino mega board with this module http://www.lightinthebox.com/es/rs232-puerto-serie-para-modulo-convertidor-ttl-para-arduino-con-transmitir-y-recibir-indicador_p1141433.html Again, it works correctly connected to PC with this code:

```cpp
void setup() {
  // initialize serial:
  Serial1.begin(9600);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello Computer");
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial1.available()) {
    Serial.println(Serial1.read());
    delay(200);
  }
  while (Serial.available()) {
    Serial1.println(Serial.read());
    delay(200);
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Then I use a male to male convertor to connect both, because both has female connections and using the same code. And it doesn't work at all.
Serial1.available() never becomes bigger than 0.
The TX from the RS232 module is connected to RX1 (19), the RX to TX1 (18), the vcc to 5V and gnd to arduino's gnd.

Comment: You can't ignore the handshake signals, you won't get them out of an Arduino.  On the device end, connect DTR with DSR, CTS with RTS.  And turn off handshaking on the device.

Comment: You may have to swap RX/TX on one side to connect the sending side's TX output to the receiving side's RX input and vice versa. Also, make sure to check what the "TX" and "RX" labels on the RS232 converter mean. On some, "TX" means "connect your TX here", while on others it means "this represents the TX of the other side".

Comment: The TX pin of the instrument should go to the RX pin of the RS232-to-TTL converter. So... you should need a null-modem cable (one with TX and RX swapped).

Comment: I'm sorry, I've already use a null cable modem (and a male-male adapter because the cable ends with female connector)